# IEnumerable<string> to MvcHtmlString: how can I make this work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
@{
   string.Join(" | ", Html.GetControllerActions().Select(x => Html.ActionLink(x.Name, x.Name)));
}
```

Basicall I have a list of strings, and I'd like use each one to create an ActionLink and separate them using a pipe. But this doesn't output anything. And how can I make it work?

**Edit:** I know that this cannot work, but it explains what I'm trying to achieve, I want to separate a list of links based on a list of strings with a pipe "|"

Comment: This is invalid or incomplete. Show us the actual code.

Comment: I edited it with the actual code. GetControllerActions() returns a IEnumerable<string> (with a single string in this particular case)

Comment: This will output nothing to renderer. Try to wrap this expression in `@Html.Raw(string.Join(...))`.

Comment: this works, i'll mark it as answer if you make it an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will output nothing to the renderer. Try to wrap this expression in `@Html.Raw(...)`:

```
@Html.Raw(string.Join(" | ", Html.GetControllerActions().Select(x => Html.ActionLink(x.Name, x.Name))))
```